# Android 6.0 notification icons are greyscaled

Tags: android, notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

The user send me the screenshot of my app about the notification icons are greyscaled. I have a colourful icons. Why?

I'm using this code to show notifications:
target api - 23.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
        Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(pIntent)
              .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(when).setContentTitle(contentTitle)
              .setContentText(contentText).setDefaults(defaults).build();
        notification.flags = flags;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you already aware about Notification icon design guidelines for lollipop and upper versions of android.

> Make sure your notifications take these Android 5.0 changes into
>   account. To learn more about designing your notifications for Android
>   5.0 and higher, see the notifications design guide.
>
> **Material design style**
>
> Notifications are drawn with dark text atop white (or very light)
>   backgrounds to match the new material design widgets. Make sure that
>   all your notifications look right with the new color scheme. If your
>   notifications look wrong, fix them:
>
> Use setColor() to set an accent color in a circle behind your icon
>   image. Update or remove assets that involve color. The system ignores
>   all non-alpha channels in action icons and in the main notification
>   icon. You should assume that these icons will be alpha-only. The
>   system draws notification icons in white and action icons in dark
>   gray.

Comment: Which format of the file  i have to use? Does it work properly with PNG files right now?

Comment: PNG would be fine.